# Working on Infinite Load in jQuery and can't get the Load function to load only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on an `Infinite Load` (e.g. Lazy Load) type functionality here is the function so far:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
       var ScrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
       var LoadMorePosition = $(document).height()-100;
       if( ScrollPosition == LoadMorePosition ) {
           console.log('loading more');
           loadMoreItems();
       }
    });
```

It's working for the most part except for that the `loadMoreItems` function is called 20-30 times once the person scrolls to the threshhold.

I was thinking a setTimeout type thing might work but on second thought I realized that it would only work if the Ajax content loaded fast enough (which isn't guaranteed).

What I need is a way to detect if they hit the threshold and then call the function only once until they hit the scroll threshold again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
var loadOnce = function(fn) {
  var loadedPages = {};
  return function(page) {
    var key = 'p'+page;
    if (typeof loadedPages[key] === 'undefined') {
      fn.apply(fn, arguments);
      loadedPages[key] = true;
    }
  };
};

var loader = loadOnce(function(page) {
  /* Ajax Request */
});

// Will only fire the ajax request once:
loader(1);
loader(1);
loader(1);
loader(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking a setTimeout type thing might work but on second thought I realized that it would only work if the Ajax content loaded fast enough (which isn't guaranteed).

Then don't rely on a timeout, instead reset the flag on the success\complete of the AJAX request.

Comment: The only way I can think to do it like that is with a Global Javascript variable, but i've heard those are bad.  Is that the only option?

Comment: @Talon, those aren't that bad as long as you control them. anyway you can create a "namespace" for your variables(google it) or save the flag in a hidden input.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX call's success part should set load more content flag, so you do not load more if you do not have more.

And for scrolling, set timeout to detect when user stops scrolling and then execute showing loading gif and do ajax, on success, hide the gif, and load more :D

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  clearTimeout(scrolled);
  scrolled = setTimeout(function(){
  //Your function when user stops scrolling
  }, 100);
});
```